# Could it be possible embed code inside a Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, function, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a very particular question. I've searched through St. Google and didn't see a feasible answer, probably what I'm trying to do is impossible.
Here's the thing.

I would like to know if it's possible embed code inside a regular expression.

Why?
Currently I have this function in order to assert some specific string (explain why I need assert this way would be complicated, let's do it later):

```js
let functionName = ()=> {
  let regex = /\w[The String]*/g;
  return stringify(regex);
};
```

So, since I have LOTS of "strings" to assert and validate, my dream function would be like this:

```js
let functionName= (theParam)=> {
  let regex = /\w[theParam]*/g;
  return stringify(regex);
};
```

I will be writing about "why in the code I have to use regex for assertions while testing!?" on my [personal blog](http://blog.moisesgonzalez.me).

Well... If this is just a dream, and it is impossible, please let me know.

Comment: Just use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)? This way you can concatenate stuff into the pattern, since it takes a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) as @MoisesGonsales mentioned along with the [escapeRegExp](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#escapeRegExp) function from the [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) or [lodash.escapeRegExp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.escaperegexp) packages:

```
const escapeRegExp = require('lodash.escapeRegExp');


function buildFunctionNameRegExp (param) {
    let escapedParam = escapeRegExp(param);

    return new RegExp(`\\w${escapedParam}*`, 'g');
};
```